# Grouping Java HashMap keys by their values

Tags: java, hashmap

Suppose I have this HashMap:

```
(key: value)
A: 3
B: 4
C: 2
D: 4
E: 1
F: 3
```

and I want to convert it to this HashMap:

```
1: {"E"}
2: {"C"}
3: {"A", "F"}
4: {"B", "D"}
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Java8 streams

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> valueMap = map.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(k -> map.get(k)));
```

Output

```
{1=[E], 2=[C], 3=[A, F], 4=[B, D]}
```

using method ref

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> valueMap = map.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(map::get));
```

to get the keys is sorted way

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> valueMap = map.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(map::get, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

In Java7 and below

```
    Map<Integer, List<String>> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        Integer val = map.get(key);
        if (valuesMap.get(val) == null) {
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
            values.add(key);
            valuesMap.put(val, values);
        } else {
            valuesMap.get(val).add(key);
        }
    }
```

output

```
{1=[E], 2=[C], 3=[A, F], 4=[B, D]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a Map of a Collection, consider using a [Multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

```
Multimap<Integer, String> multimap = HashBasedMultimap.create()
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  multimap.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
}
```